# Create alias in windows start menu search

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I'd like to customize the results that show up when I type something into windows search.

For example, when I type `VPN` into the start menu search, I'd like `PIA` / `Private Internet Access` to show up.

Is there anyway to customize the search index with custom results / synonyms?

[image: app search]

---

One potential entry point is in the search index configuration in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppsConstraintIndex
```

Which points the search index to the following folder:

```bsh
%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\ConstraintIndex\Input_{72d1f533-1b2e-4d21-ada0-50ddf69bb425}
```

There are two existing files which create aliases:

- `appssynonyms.txt`
- `settingssynonyms.txt`

Which helps cover misspellings and other synonyms:

```
*|notepad   *|notwepad  13003
*|notepad   *|notyepad  11800
*|notepad   *|noytepad  12501
*|notepad   *|npotepad  12159
```

How can you extend / customize this list?

Comment: Search will find files and shortcuts on your computer, so just create a shortcut to the resource you want and give it the name you wish to find it by in search. Note, this is rather inefficient and there are better ways to make short codes open applications or files. Create a folder, add it to your Path, and place shortcuts in it with the names you wish. Open CMD and type the string you want and click OK, which is going to be faster and more precise than using Search.

Comment: Where does `appssynonyms.txt`  file is located?

Comment: @alper - should be in the question, but I think there's a unique GUID so it's going to be slightly different for all users - look in `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search...`

Answer (score 2):

I've found one way to do this is by using the [App Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#using-the-app-paths-subkey) functionality in the registry, also described by Raymond Chen in his article "[How is it possible to run Wordpad by just typing its name even though it isn’t on the PATH?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110725-00/?p=10073)".

You can add a key to one of these registry paths with the format `<alias>.exe`:

- Machine-wide: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`
- Current user-only: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

So for your example, a new key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\vpn.exe`.

Inside the key, the `(Default)` string value should be set to the path of the `.exe`. You can also set the `Path` string value to a directory path that you'd like added to the `PATH` environment variable when launching the app.

Here's an example where "vpn" would open up 7-Zip:

[image: Screenshot of the Registry Editor showing a new App Paths entry for vpn.exe, with its Default string value pointed at 7-Zip's 7zFM.exe as an example.]

Once those have been set, you should be able to type "vpn" in the Start Menu search to bring up the command (it might not be the first suggestion):

[image: Screenshot of the Windows 10 Start Menu showing "vpn" show up as a "Run command" entry after searching for the phrase "vpn".]

You should also be able to type "vpn" directly into the Run dialogue (`Win` + `R`) to launch the application:

[image: Screenshot of the Windows 10 Run dialogue with the word "vpn" typed into it.]

Comment: Is it possible to have two aliases for the same program without creating two keys on the registry? Something like both "zip" or "7z" pointing to 7zip.exe

Comment: @olenscki I'm not aware of a way to do that without two registry keys. Windows itself uses both `WORDPAD.EXE` and `WRITE.EXE` to point at `"%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\WORDPAD.EXE"` on my machine.

Comment: By the way, from command line it seems you can only start it  with `start <alias>`. And if it's CLI tool you'd better do `start /B <alias>`